# How to extend doc() functionality in saxon

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

I am looking for an extension of doc() functionality currently available in SAXON in a way that it will read XML not from filesystem or from http network, but from memory, where I have those xmls.

The way I want to use it is like:

```
mydoc('id')/root/subroot/@myattr
```

or

```
doc('mydoc://id')/root/subroot/@myattr
```

What I have considered so far:

1. use queryEvaluator.setContextItem() - does not solve my use case as I can have multiple XML sources in one query
2. register some own URL scheme protocol into Java - seems to me like overkill and I have never done this
3. write own ExtensionFunction - seems to be the right way so far, but i am confused whether I should use ExtensionFunction or rather ExtensionFunctionDefinition. Also I am littel bit confused by Doc_1 and Doc Saxonica source  code as it uses Atomizer and other unknown internall stuff.

**So the questions are:**

1. Is it variant 3 the best one (in the means of simplicity) or would you recommend some other approach ?
2. Is it OK to use ExtensionFunction and return XdmNode from my in-memory xmls ? It seems to me it should work, but I really do not want to step into some edge cases or saxon minefield.

Any comment from experienced Saxon user will be appretiated.

Comment: You can use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XQueryEvaluator.html#setURIResolver-javax.xml.transform.URIResolver- to set your own implementation of the JAXP interface URIResolver https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html

Comment: One example to implement URIResolver is in the online book http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s02.html#d0e32363, this is not related to Saxon but as Saxon uses the JAXP interface that is part of the JRE/JDK standard library the example should serve as a good starting point if you want to see an example of how to implement the interface.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for pointing out on how to use&implement URIResolver, I will go by this way as it is more simplier than I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is to write a `URIResolver` and register it with the transformer. The `URIResolver` is called, supplying the requested URI, and it is expected to return a Source (which can be a `StreamSource`, `SAXSource`, or `DOMSource`, for example). In this scenario you would typically return a `StreamSource` wrapping a `StringReader` which wraps the `String` containing the XML.

You could equally well use an extension function, but it's probably a little bit more complicated.